# Geometry problem of directed line segment

Tags: geometry

I have taken this problem from "Geometry Revisited" by H.S.M Coxeter and S.L Greitzer.

A line through the centroid G of triangle ABC intersects the sides of the triangle at points X,Y,Z. Using the concept of directed line segments, prove:
1/GX + 1/GY + 1/GZ = 0.

a. Can anyone give me the sketch of the problem.
b. The method to solve the problem.

Thank you all.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the notation. What does $GX$ exactly mean?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422265/a-line-through-the-centroid-g-of-triangle-abc-intersects-the-sides-at-points) (asked 5 days ago), in which the OP provides (edited in)  a diagram and the proof outlines in the book. I can't vote to close as it has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd work on this in barycentric homogenous coordinates. This means that your corners correspond to the unit vectors of $\mathbb R^3$, that scalar multiples of a vector describe the same point. You can check for incidence between points and lines using the scalar product, and you can connect points and intersect lines using the cross product. **This solution is influenced heavily by my background in projective geometry.** In this world you have

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad
C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
G = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad
l = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ a \\ -1-a \end{pmatrix} \qquad
\left<G,l\right> = 0 \\
X = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad
Y = \begin{pmatrix} 1+a \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad
Z = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1+a \\ a \end{pmatrix}
$$

The coordinates of $l$ were chosen such that the line $l$ already passes through $G$, as seen by the scalar product. The single parameter $a$ corresponds roughly to the slope of the line. The special case where the line passes through $A$ isn't handled, since in that case the first coordinate of $l$ would have to be $0$ (or $a$ would have to be $\infty$). But simply renaming the corners of your triangle would cover that case as well.

In order to obtain lengths, I'd fix a projective scale on this line $l$. For this you need the point at infinity on $F$. You can obtain it by intersecting $l$ with the line at infinity.

$$ F = l\times\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 2a+1 \\ -2-a \\ 1-a \end{pmatrix} $$

To complete your projective scale, you also need to fix an origin, i.e. a point with coordinate “zero”, and a unit length, i.e. a point with coordinate “one”. Since all distances in your formula are measured from $G$, it makes sense to use that as the zero point. And since you could multiply all your lengths by a common scale factor without affecting the formula you stated, the choice of scale is irrelevant. Therefore we might as well choose $X$ as one. Note that this choice also fixes the orientation of length measurements along your line: positive is from $G$ in direction of $X$. We can then compute the two remaining coordinates, those of $Y$ and $Z$, using the cross ratio. In the following formula, square brackets denote determinants. The cross ratio of four collinear points in the plane can be computed as seen from some fifth point not on that line. I'll use $A$ for this purpose, both because it has simple coordinates and because, as stated above, the case of $l$ passing through $A$ has been omitted by the choice of coordinates for $l$.

$$
GY = \operatorname{cr}(F,G;X,Y)_A =
\frac{[AFX][AGY]}{[AFY][AGX]} =
\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2a+1 & a \\
0 & -2-a & -1 \\
0 & 1-a & 0
\end{vmatrix}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1+a \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2a+1 & 1+a \\
0 & -2-a & 0 \\
0 & 1-a & 1
\end{vmatrix}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & a \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}}
= \frac{a-1}{a+2}
\\
GZ = \operatorname{cr}(F,G;X,Z)_A =
\frac{[AFX][AGZ]}{[AFZ][AGX]} =
\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2a+1 & a \\
0 & -2-a & -1 \\
0 & 1-a & 0
\end{vmatrix}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1+a \\
0 & 1 & a
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2a+1 & 0 \\
0 & -2-a & 1+a \\
0 & 1-a & a
\end{vmatrix}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & a \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}}
= \frac{1-a}{1+2a}
$$

The thrid length, $GX$, is $1$ by the definition of the projective scale. So now you have the three lengths and plug them into your formula.

$$
\frac1{GX} + \frac1{GY} + \frac1{GZ} =
\frac{a-1}{a-1} + \frac{a+2}{a-1} - \frac{2a+1}{a-1} = 0
$$

As you will notice, the case of $a=1$ is problematic in this setup, since it would entail a division by zero. This corresponds to the situation where $l$ is parallel to $AB$. In that case, the point $X$ which we used as the “one” of the scale would coincide with the point $F$ at infinity, thus breaking the scale. A renaming of triangle corners will again take care of this special case. The cases $a=-2$ and $a=-\tfrac12$ correspond to the two other cases where $l$ is parallel to one of the edges. You will notice that the lengths would again entail divisions by zero, since the points of intersection are infinitely far away. But the reciprocal lengths are just fine and will be zero in those cases.

Comment: Could you please alos post this answer on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422265/a-line-through-the-centroid-g-of-triangle-abc-intersects-the-sides-at-points ?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: thanks for the pointer, did that.